# Adding commons-net jar to build.gradle file

Tags: java, jar, cmd, gradle, dependencies

I have this line in myEclipse

```
import org.apache.commons.net.util.SubnetUtils;
```

And I have the JAR file imported in the build path (commons-net-3.3.jar). I have commons-lang3 added to my dependencies in build.gradle and it works fine but when I add commons-net to it, cmd gives me an error saying it can't find commons-net. Here is my code snippet for the dependencies in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.11"
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.3.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-net', version: '3.3'
  }
```

What do I have to change to fix this error?

Comment: do an clean install on the project after adding the lines to the pom...

Comment: I already tried "gradle clean build" but it throws the same error.

Comment: in the repository section you have the repo where this jar is coming from ?

Comment: Yes. This is the error it shows me:

"Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':apps:testRuntime'.
> Could not find org.apache.commons:commons-net:3.3."

Comment: check the repo url in browser and see if you can find this version of the jar ... e.g. : http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/

Answer (score 10):

In maven central repository the `group` part is also `commons-net`. See [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22commons-net%22%20AND%20a%3A%22commons-net%22). The whole entry should be:

`compile 'commons-net:commons-net:3.3'`

Answer (score 2):

Change compile group: `org.apache.commons` to `commons-net` to fix this issue.
Try these:
`dependencies {
  compile group: 'commons-net', name: 'commons-net', version: '3.3'
}`